# Why throw is deprecated in solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-20

Why throw is deprecated in solidity?

Is there any drawbacks?

I also found below on [Github](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1793)

`Even if we remove throw as a feature, the keyword should be kept. We might be able to introduce something in the future.`

So what type of implementation will be done by throw in future? Is there any proposal set for this yet? Is there any documentation where I can find details related to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solidity [documents](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) simply describes difference between throw and revert.

> There are two other ways to trigger exceptions: The revert function can be used to flag an error and revert the current call. In the future it might be possible to also include details about the error in a call to revert. The throw keyword can also be used as an alternative to revert()

For a call of changing status failed, `revert` will refund unused gas, but `throw` not. and the same is all status would get rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use revert() or any of the shown error and replace the throw()